# Unity Google Cardboard SDK vs iOS 10

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, ios10

I have a problem with GoogleCardboard (for Unity) and iOS-10 beta (with iPhone-5).
I updated SDK at https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download 
and built sample app by Xcode (Version 8.0 beta 2 (8S162m)).

with iPhone5 - iOS-10 beta,
when I opened, after UnityLogo disappeared, app crashed suddenly.
I also downloaded 2 GoogleCardboard apps on AppStore (link from Google Cardboard app), but they also didn't worked (one can go to the cardboard UI, but cardboard sensor didn't worked).

iOS-8.0 (iPhone-5s, iPhone-6) and iOS-9 (iPhone-6) are ok.

What can I do? How repair this problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: How did you update the SDK? Whats steps did you follow?

Comment: I cloned gvr-unity-sdk to my computer. Then I built the DemoScene on HeadsetDemo folder (Unity 5.2.5p6, ScriptingBackend is IL2CPP). 
Then at Xcode(8.0beta2), I set Deployment target = 10.0, then built enterprise app.